# Issues with Windows Storage Space GUI

Tags: storage-spaces

Two parts question:

1. I have Simple Storage Space consisting of 3 small old SSDs which I created long time ago and barely used since. Now I wanted to remove one physical drive but even though 2 of 3 drives can be removed (because it is simple and all data are less than largest drive) there are no 'Prepare for removal' links available! I had to run `Set-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName 'name' -Usage Retired` and reboot the computer to be able to really remove it. Before reboot it said something like 'add another drive to remove this one'. Basically, it behaved like resilient storage space with lowest possible number of drives, which is absurd. Now the second drive, which should be also removable, still lacks 'Prepare for removal' link. Why?
   [image]
2. There is still that weird behavior on resizing existing Storage Space. You cannot change the size even though there is an option for that, because to any number I put there it says 'Size is not valid'. It behaves like this for years so it probably is not a bug but more likely I completely missed something about resizing, but what?
   [image]